# Do while loop code wont play

Tags: vba, loops, do-while

I am trying to loop through a list of data then and copy the rows that contain "WIP" into a second tab. yet the code will nor do anything when I hit execute. Can someone explain why?

Thank you.

```
Sub Update_LvL1_WIP()

Dim BrowFi As Integer

Dim BrowWIP1 As Integer

Dim dblSKU As Double
Dim strDescription As String
Dim strType As String


BrowFi = (ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) + 1

Do While BrowFi > 4

    If Range("G" & BrowFi).Value = "WIP" Then

       strType = Range("G" & BrowFi).Value
       strDescription = Range("F" & BrowFi).Value
       dblSKU = Range("E" & BrowFi).Value

       Worksheets("WIP 1").Activate

           BrowWIP1 = (ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) +1

                Range("A" & BrowWIP1).Value = dblSKU
                Range("B" & BrowWIP1).Value = strDescription
                Range("B" & BrowWIP1).Value = strType

    Else

        BrowFi = BrowiF - 1

    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you see when you step through it with the debugger (while viewing the contents of the various variables in the locals window)?

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your decrement variable

```
BrowFi = BrowiF - 1
```

should be

```
BrowFi = BrowFi - 1
```

Since `BrowiF` was not defined it was treated as `0` and so you were setting `BrowFi` to `-1` on the first run through the loop.

It may be worth using [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx) to help catch these errors.

Comment: Good catch and worthy of an upvote.  Perhaps you could edit your answer to include a mention of the importance of Option Explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the code still will not run and gives me no error messages. could it be something that is not related to my code?

Comment: You have to debug your code. Watch out for values. I think problem is related to the excel data. Check out the value of BrowFi just after this line-`BrowFi = (ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) + 1`

Comment: First, Add "Option Explicit" to the top of your module and then compile. This is the first step you need to do. Second, If you are able to compile, then you are ready to debug. Place a breakpoint on your first line of executing code (after the Dim statements) and then step through the code line by line checking the values as you go to see if they are as expected.

Comment: The error is on the line: "If Range("G" & BrowF).Value = Range("G3").Value Then.." as the value in Range("G" & BrowF) is a vlookup that returns either an NA or a value. is there a way to make it work? or do I need to make a hard copy of the values

Comment: I don't see the line you are referring to in the code above. Is this a new part of the code, or is your code above outdated?